# Multiple parallel API calls and subscribe to it sequentially

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I want to make multiple parallel API calls using the same endpoint but different parameters. And subscribe to it if any of the request is complete. How can I handle this. This is my current approach. I am unsure of how to make parallel api calls and subscribe to it sequentially. Please suggest the better approach.

```
getProductDetails(id) {
  return this.http.get(
    `https://dummyjson.com/products/get_details?id=${id}`
  );
}

createProductDetails(productDetails)  {
}

ngOnInit() {
  const ids = ["a","b", "c", "d", "e", "f"];

  // api calls should happen in parallel manner
  from(ids).pipe(mergeMap((item) => {
    return this.getProductDetails(item)
  })).subscribe(response => {
    // it should create product details whenever response for any of the product is ready
    // this function should get called 6 times since their are 6 products
    this.createProductDetails(response)
  });
}
```

End goal is to make parallel api calls and start showing data as soon as the response is ready for any of the item

Comment: You're description is pretty confusing. _"how to make parallel api calls and subscribe to it sequentially"_ ... so which one you want?

Comment: It sounds like you just want to subscribe to each api call individually? Maybe ids.forEach(item =>  this.getProducDetails(item). subscribe.....

Comment: Do you mean you want to execute all requests at the same time, only emit responses in order? For example if all requests are made, and response B returns before response A, wait for A, then emit A, then B?

Comment: What I meant is, fire all requests at once, and the order of response doesn't matter. Also it should not wait for all requests to get resolved. If B comes before A then emit B.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: It looks like your current code should give that behavior.  What behavior are you seeing with your current code?

Comment: @BizzyBob I am unsure whether they are getting fired all at once or one after another.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what the purpose of the pipe is in this situation. But I would suggest something like this using simple JavaScript promises.

```js
getProductDetails(id) {
  return this.http.get(
    `https://dummyjson.com/products/get_details?id=${id}`
  );
}

createProductDetails(productDetails)  {
}

ngOnInit() {
  const ids = ["a","b", "c", "d", "e", "f"];

  // get details for each id in parallel
  ids.forEach(id => {
    this.getProductDetails(id)
    .then(response => {
       // whenever a response is ready
       this.createProductDetails(response)
     })
  })
}
```

If you want to know when all promises have completed you can change forEach into map like so.

```js
// get details for each id in parallel
const tasks = ids.map(id => {
  this.getProductDetails(id)
  .then(response => {
     // whenever a response is ready
     this.createProductDetails(response)
   })
})

// using .then()
Promise.all(tasks)
.then(() => console.log("tasks completed"))
```

Comment: In the above approach, the requests are getting fired in a loop (one after another), not at once.

Comment: @developer So there is 0 parallel? Then instead of promise.all you can use promise.any and it will only use the first task that has succeeded. Move .then with the "whenever a response is ready" comment, to after promise.all(). If this is what you meant I will update the answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [CombineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest)
In this you can calls multiple API's simultaneously and get the response in one shot.

```
combineLatest(
  API1,
  API2,
  API3
)
  .subscribe(
    ([res1, res2, res3]) => {
  console.log(res1)
  console.log(res2)
  console.log(res3)
})
```

Comment: combineLatest will fire all the requests at once which is correct, but I don't want to wait for all requests to be resolved. It should emit the response as soon as any one of them is ready.

Comment: then you can use toPromise() for each API call and.